# Trouble With Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter to make a simple number guessing game in python 2.7. I am having trouble with getting Tkinter work for me. It tells me that for lines 6-8 "'x' may be undefined, or defined from the star imports: Tkinter"

```
import random
from Tkinter import * 
import tkMessageBox
import tkSimpleDialog

top = Tkinter.Tk()
root = Tk ()
w = Lable(root, text='Number Game')
```

Comment: This code has multiple other serious bugs: (1) You can't do `Tkinter.Tk` if you did `from Tkinter import *` instead of `import Tkinter`. (2) You can't create two `Tk()` root objects. (3) There's no such thing as `Lable`, so that's a `NameError`.

Comment: Also, what is the "it" that's telling you this? Are you running a linter and seeing linter warnings? Or using an IDE that does that for you automatically? Or getting warnings printing out when you run the script? Or raising exceptions when you run the script? Or…?

Comment: There is no `x` anywhere in this code...